# External and internal resistance to airflow

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, drag

If an aircraft was travelling at 100mph an hole was opened to allow 100mph into the cabin,then the airflow is feed into an amplifier like a ramjet and the airflow out of the ramjet was increased to 300mph, the now internally produced increased 300mph airflow then hits a flat surface, is the resistance that hits the flat surface the sum of the internally produced extra 200mph ie 300 -100 external mph or is it just the original 100mph that hit the internal ramjet or is it the full 300mph, so what resistance to forward motion of the aircraft is produced

Answer (score 0):

The terminology you use seems a little loose, air resistance, a type of friction,   is a force acting opposite to the relative motion of any object moving with respect to a surrounding fluid, so it is not measured in mph but in force units.

But to answer your question, when the airflow leaves the amplifier it produces a force or a change in momentum onto the amplifier. the magnitude of this force is similar but in the opposite direction that the one it imparted on the air (because of the third Newton law). The net result is that the effect of the amplifier (if attached to the airplane) is irrelevant. The air resistance will be the one generated by the original 100 mph flow.

Another way to see this is that, seen from outside the plane, the amplifier only generates internal forces,  and internal forces do not have any effect on the dynamics (if object that does not split or deforms, like in this case), only external forces do (the 100 mph flow).